# Can I use a single device to control other devices in the Home Graph?

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home

I would like to build a Smart Home device that can be setup to control other devices in the Home Graph. What's the cleanest way to do this?

For instance, if a press on an Amazon Dash Button created a data flow:
Dash Button sends MQTT -> Server IoT Receives --> Forwarded to Google Cloud --> "Turns on TV, Turns on Lights".

I understand / assume that I cannot directly control 3rd party devices using my own hardware.

Is it possible to control devices through Google Home using the Google Assistant SDK... But I'm a little confused how my custom Amazon button (or any hardware) would fit into the larger picture. If it calls the Google Assistant SDK, it's not a Smart Home Device anymore, is it -- Not part of the Home Graph?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for you to directly control other Home Graph devices from your Home Graph device.